# Unoconv and IIS perimission issues

Tags: php, windows, iis, unoconv

Looking for some advise on setting up Unoconv on IIS.

I am trying to run this via PHP but I get the following error.

```
Verbosity set to level 3
Using office base path: C:\Program Files\LibreOffice
Using office binary path: C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program
DEBUG: Connection type: socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext
DEBUG: Existing listener not found.
DEBUG: Launching our own listener using C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe.
LibreOffice listener arguments are ['C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice\\program\\soffice.exe', '--headless', '--invisible', '--nocrashreport', '--nodefault', '--nofirststartwizard', '--nologo', '--norestore', '--accept=socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext'].
LibreOffice listener successfully started. (pid=8808)
Failed to connect to C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe (pid=8808) in 6 seconds.
Connector : couldn't connect to socket (WSAECONNREFUSED, Connection refused)
Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.
```

- If I run the following command in CMD `unoconv --listener` prior to running the PHP script to convert the file everything works as expected, but I do not want to manage the listener creation process myself as unoconv should do this.
- If I switch the App Pool Identity to `LocalSystem` everything works the listener gets created and file conversion work, but this is giving too much access.

Any Ideas as to what I need to configure to get this to work via the usual `ApplicationPoolIdentity` ?

Thank you

Ged

Answer (score 1):

Give `NAME_OF_YOUR_MACHINE\IIS_IUSRS` permissions on the relevant folders and try to use AppPoolIdentity